# Finding if a TextBox/Label caption fits in the control

Tags: vba, excel

The scenario is trying to adjust font size to get a nice graphic arrangement, or trying to decide where to break a caption/subtitle.
a) In XL VBA is there a way to find out whether a text on a textbox, or caption on a label, still fits the control?
b) Is there a way to know where was the text/caption broken on multiline control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I gave this a rest, gave it enough back-of-head time (which produces far better results than "burp a non-answer ASAP, for credits"), and...

```
Function TextWidth(aText As String, Optional aFont As NewFont) As Single
    Dim theFont As New NewFont
    Dim notSeenTBox As Control

    On Error Resume Next 'trap for aFont=Nothing
    theFont = aFont 'try assign

    If Err.Number Then 'can't use aFont because it's not instantiated/set
        theFont.Name = "Tahoma"
        theFont.Size = 8
        theFont.Bold = False
        theFont.Italic = False
    End If
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    'make a TextBox, fiddle with autosize et al, retrive control width
    Set notSeenTBox = UserForms(0).Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "notSeen1", False)
    notSeenTBox.MultiLine = False
    notSeenTBox.AutoSize = True 'the trick
    notSeenTBox.Font.Name = theFont.Name
    notSeenTBox.SpecialEffect = 0
    notSeenTBox.Width = 0 ' otherwise we get an offset (a ""feature"" from MS)
    notSeenTBox.Text = aText
    TextWidth = notSeenTBox.Width
    'done with it, to scrap I say
    UserForms(0).Controls.Remove ("notSeen1")
    Exit Function

ErrHandler:
    TextWidth = -1
    MsgBox "TextWidth failed: " + Err.Description
End Function
```

I feel I'm getting/got close to answer b), but I'll give it a second mind rest... because it works better than stating "impossible" in a flash.

Comment: You first comment (> BTW, Jeff Atwood team...) would need to go to meta.stackoverflow.com. very nice idea by the way. i was looking for pretty much the same thing and i ended up here (finally ended up using a variation of your idea). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is no way to do this with the ordinary Excel controls on the Forms toolbar, not least because (as I understand it) they are simply drawings and not full Windows controls.

The simplest approach may be to make a slightly conservative estimate of the maximum text length for each control, through a few tests, and use these to manage your line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by taking advantage of the label or textbox's .AutoSize feature, and looping through font sizes until you reach the one that fits best.

```
Public Sub ResizeTextToFit(Ctrl As MSForms.Label)   'or TextBox
    
    Const FONT_SHRINKAGE_FACTOR As Single = 0.9 'For more accuracy, use .95 or .99
    
    Dim OrigWidth As Single
    Dim OrigHeight As Single
    Dim OrigLeft As Single
    Dim OrigTop As Single
    
    With Ctrl
        If .Caption = "" Then Exit Sub
        .AutoSize = False
        OrigWidth = .Width
        OrigHeight = .Height
        OrigLeft = .Left
        OrigTop = .Top
        Do
            .AutoSize = True
            If .Width <= OrigWidth And .Height <= OrigHeight Then
                Exit Do     'The font is small enough now
            .Font.Size = .Font.Size * FONT_SHRINKAGE_FACTOR
            .AutoSize = False
        Loop
        .AutoSize = False
        .Width = OrigWidth
        .Height = OrigHeight
        .Left = OrigLeft
        .Top = OrigTop
    End With

End Sub
```